# How to update combobox when it references a different table than the form

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

In my form "Quote Form", the user first enters a customer name, which causes other fields within the form (Street Address, Buyer, etc.) to auto-fill with content that corresponds to the known customer information. The customer information is stored in a separate, linked table "Customer Information." One particular field "Buyer" is represented by a combobox "BuyerEntry" in this form. The combobox's dropdown list is populated by three fields in the "Customer Information" table - "Buyer (Primary)", "Buyer (Secondary)", and "Buyer (Tertiary)."

After the user enters the customer's name in the form, if they edit the auto-filled information for the "BuyerEntry" control to something other than the existing information for any of the three buyer fields found within "Customer Information", the user is asked if they would like to update the information in "Customer Information" to reflect the information that they entered.

My code for doing this is shown below. Essentially, it checks if there are any open "Buyer" fields within "Customer Information" that the data can be added to. If all of these fields are full, it gives the user the opportunity to update any of the fields with the new information that they entered.

```
Private Sub BuyerEntry_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
'Check for match with existing customer information and update if necessary
Dim MsgBoxAnswer As Variant
Response = acDataErrContinue

'Request Permission to update customer information based on conflicting entries
MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("The buyer does not match what is currently listed for this customer. Would you like to update the customer's information to match?", vbYesNo, "Edit Customer Information?")
If MsgBoxAnswer = vbNo Then 'No permission granted to update information
    Me.BuyerEntry = Null
    Exit Sub
Else 'Permission granted to update information
    If IsNull(DLookup("[Buyer (Primary)]", "[Customer Information]", "[Customer Name] = CustomerEntry.Value")) = True Then 'If the primary buyer position is empty, update the customer information to include the entered buyer here
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Primary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsNull(DLookup("[Buyer (Secondary)]", "[Customer Information]", "[Customer Name] = CustomerEntry.Value")) = True Then 'If the secondary buyer position is empty, update the customer information to include the entered buyer here
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Secondary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsNull(DLookup("[Buyer (Tertiary)]", "[Customer Information]", "[Customer Name] = CustomerEntry.Value")) = True Then 'If the tertiary buyer position is empty, update the customer information to include the entered buyer here
        DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Tertiary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
        Exit Sub
    Else 'If all buyer positions are already filled, ask the user if they would like to update the primary buyer position
        MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to update this to be the customer's primary buyer?", vbYesNo, "Update Primary Buyer?")
        If MsgBoxAnswer = vbYes Then 'Permission granted to update primary buyer position
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Primary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
            Exit Sub
        Else 'No permission granted to update primary buyer position. Ask the user if they would like to update the secondary buyer position
            MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to update this to be the customer's secondary buyer?", vbYesNo, "Update Secondary Buyer?")
            If MsgBoxAnswer = vbYes Then 'Permission granted to update secondary buyer position
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Secondary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
                Exit Sub
            Else 'No permission granted to update secondary buyer position. Ask the user if they would like to update the tertiary buyer position
                MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Would you like to update this to be the customer's tertiary buyer?" & vbCrLf & "Note: This is the last opportunity to update the customer's buyer information.", vbYesNo, "Update Tertiary Buyer?")
                If MsgBoxAnswer = vbYes Then 'Permission granted to update tertiary buyer position
                    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Customer Information] SET [Buyer (Tertiary)] = '" & NewData & "' WHERE [Customer Name] = '" & Form.Controls("CustomerEntry") & "'"
                    Exit Sub
                Else 'No Permission granted to update tertiary buyer position
                    Me.BuyerEntry = Null 'Make the list control empty for the time being
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The code does not generate any errors. However, after the user has updated the information within "Customer Information", the dropdown list of the combobox does not change to reflect this updated information. As a result, it triggers the "NotInList" event again and, as a result, the user is left to loop through this code continually unless they click out of the control on the form, at which point the control does update. I would like the dropdown list in the control to update immediately following the user's changes to "Customer Information" such that the "NotInList" event is not triggered and the user can tab out of this control.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this error and/or further improve my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requery the combobox with

```
myComboBox.Requery
```

Comment: I have tried that. However, when I add the Requery command, I get the following error: "Run-time error '2118': You must save the current field before you run the Requery action." Then, when I try to use "Forms![Quote Form].Dirty = False" to save the form, it gives me an error stating that "No current record can be found"

Comment: Try re-assigning the RowSource of the combobox.